# React native navigate to specific screen of bottom tabs from inner screen

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to navigate from one inner screen to third tab of Bottom Tab Navigation.
Here is my Stack Navigator:

```
<Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false,
    animationEnabled: true,
    orientation: 'portrait',
  }}>
  <Screen name="BottomTabs" component={BottomTabs} />
  <Screen
    name="CreateWorkout"
    component={CreateWorkout}
    options={horizontalAnimation}
  />
  <Screen
    name="NewWorkout"
    component={NewWorkout}
    options={horizontalAnimation}
  />
  <Screen
    name="StartWorkout"
    component={StartWorkout}
    options={horizontalAnimation}
  />
</Navigator>
```

Here is my Bottom Tab Navigator:

```
const BottomTabs = () => {
return (
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
  <Stack.Screen name="RootHome" component={RootHome} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Create" component={CreateWorkoutScreen} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Progress" component={MyProgressScreen} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
</Stack.Navigator>
 );
};
```

I want to navigate from "StartWorkout" to "Progress" screen in Bottom Tabs.

```
navigation.navigate('BottomTabs', {screen: 'Progress'});
```

Any help can be appreciated.

I have tried this code it does navigate to that particular screen but it hides the BottomTabs

Answer (score 0):

I think that to do this, you have to put the "StartWorkout" screen inside the "BottomTabs" component, so it would navigate to the "Progress" screen without hiding the bottom tabs.

Comment: I have tried it but it keeps hiding the bottom tabs.

Comment: Could you provide the code with the StartWorkout inside the Bottom tabs component?